# importing maven projects into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am doing [this tutorial,](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/) and am trying to import [this project](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase) into eclipse.  The problem is that the tutorial does not give an adequate explanation of how to import the project into eclipse.

I have the springsource tool suite plugin installed, and I am using windows 7.

The tutorial uses a mac to open up a terminal, and type in:

```
svn checkout https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-showcase
```

and a bunch of directories appear.  But when I type in that command in c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe, I get:

```
'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file
```

I am probably using 64 bit versions of eclipse, sts, etc.  But it would be nice to have some way of importing projects using a gui instead of having to resort to the command line.

Can anyone either write out or direct me to explicit, step-by-step instructions for how to import a maven project into eclipse kepler using the m2e plugin, preferably through a gui?

Comment: Eclipse has an SVN plugin; consider using it. Maven and SVN are orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the svn client first on your windows machine. svn is a code control tool, using which you can connect to a code repository to checkout or checkin the code. You can download svn client from here:

http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/

Once you checkout the code/project, then you can import in eclipse. If it is a maven project then you should have maven eclipse plugin(m2e) installed. Follow this link to install m2e eclipse plugin:

http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

Use TortoiseSVN to download from the repository (as mentioned), which provides an excellent GUI.

Then, you can generate an Eclipse project from Maven by using the Maven Eclipse plugin from the command line, and use the GUI to import from there (like so):

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

[The Documentation has more info.](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html)

I know you prefer a GUI option, but I've found the results to be much more reliable than the M2E plugin.  I use IntelliJ community edition now in preference to Eclipse, because Maven import just *works* without any fiddling at all.